# Syncfusion Datagrid crashes Xamarin IOS application due to initiallising of control

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datagrid, syncfusion, argumentnullexception

I have a Xamarin application in which I have included the Syncfusion Datagrid control. I am trying to deploy this to an IOS simulator in visual studio. I have added the NuGet package and included a community license. However, it wasn't displaying on the screen. To fix this I added the following line of code, as advised by https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/137574/no-visible-data-grid-on-ios-platform-only.

```
Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.iOS.SfDataGridRenderer.Init();
```

However, this now results in my application crashing with the only debugger info being:

main.cs:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      // if you want to use a different Application Delegate class from "AppDelegate"
      // you can specify it here.
      UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate"); #System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'
}
```

AppDelegate.cs:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
      Syncfusion.SfDataGrid.XForms.iOS.SfDataGridRenderer.Init();
      LoadApplication(new App());

      return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
}
```

If I haven't given you enough info about my setup please just ask and I will happily provide it. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you added a try/catch block around the suspect line of code?

Comment: @Jason I have, however because the UIApplication.Main function is a very broad command i havent been able to get anything useful... Do you know a better way to gather debugging information?

Comment: add appcenter.ms crash reporting.  The crash is not actually happening in Main, it just looks like that when an unhandled crash occurs.

Comment: Sorry @Jason ive never used that before... do you have a link / tutorial i can follow to show me how to use this to find the root of the error? Thanks again

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/getting-started/xamarin#423-xamarinforms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the cause of the problem was, however, by downgrading my Xamarin.Forms and Xamarin.Essentials package to versions 4.5.0.495 and 1.3.1 respectively I no longer got the error and the screen was displayed properly.

I figured this out by making a new test project and trying to recreate my code. Then I tried running it and it worked. Thus I changed the versions of my original code to the versions that worked in the project that was generated by a Xamarin template.

Thanks everyone for their help :)

Answer (score 1):

I too have experienced this same issue; after recent updates, my app crashed with a null exception on the `main.cs` in iOS. I finally isolated and resolved what was triggering the issue.

The problem occurred when I populated a `SfDataGrid` with more rows than could fit on a (cross platform, iOS) simulator screen; this would trigger a crash as soon as I tried to scroll vertically or horizontally. If the number of rows was less than the screen size, however, it didn't crash. The app also worked fine a week or so ago.

It turns out that there appears to be a bug in the latest release of Xamarin.Forms version 4.6.0.968. By downgrading Xamarin.Forms to version 4.6.0.847, the problem was resolved.

The following link provides further details On this issue:

- https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/155376/sfdatagrid-crashes-app-when-user-start-to-scroll-the-content-18-1-0-57
- https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11132

Comment: Assuming you didn’t accidentally delete your own answer, it was likely deleted by either reviewers or a high-reputation user for not meeting Stack Overflow’s standards for an answer. If the text was identical to this repost, it _may_ have been due to the _tense_ of your first sentence; on quick review, it sounded like you _still_ had the problem. We get a lot of answers saying “I have this issue too” without actually providing a resolution. I’ve reworded your answer so it’s clearer that you were able to isolate and resolve this. While I was at it, I also made some small edits for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the renderer initialization if you are using Xamarin.iOS platform and not the cross-platform.

In case, if you are using the iOS version of Xamarin.Forms, then [refer the getting started documentation here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/datagrid/getting-started) to know the step by step configuration of the DataGrid component. Confirm that you have installed the [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid) NuGet package.

In case, if you are using the Xamarin.iOS platform itself, then please [refer the documentation here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-ios/sfdatagrid/getting-started) for the step by step configurations and be sure that you have installed the [Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid.IOS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfDataGrid.ios) package.

I hope that helps.

Comment: sorry i should have been more clear. my application is a cross platform xamarin forms app, thus it has generic, IOS, Android, and UWP parts. I am only concerned about the IOS part as it is the only part i have had trouble with... :)

Comment: I just checked and everything seems to be up to scratch regarding what you have highlighted... Any other ideas?

Comment: Try comparing your sample with the example demo here to narrow down. https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/DataGrid-GettingStarted-in-Xamarin-Forms

Comment: Because without knowing what is thrown as null, it is not possible to proceed further. Or maybe try uploading a demo of what you tried, that would be easier to help.